# Is any non-zero scalar of the unit disc also compact?

Tags: general-topology, complex-numbers, compactness

There is the circle group which is specifically a set of points comprising the boundary of the unit disc in the complex plane which turns out to be a compact set.

However, is the set of points forming a circle of any arbitrary radius also compact in the complex plane?

Comment: Yes, of course. You can equally scale the open covers as well..

Comment: See you say "of course" but if it was trivial then no one would bother proving compactness of something as simple as closed/bounded subsets sets in $\mathbb{R}$ either, and then there wouldn't be a rigorous definition of a subset nor closedness nor boundedness.

Comment: (Of course) Berci isn't saying, "Of course the circle is compact". He's saying, "Since you already know that the boundary of the unit disc is compact..."---after all, that was asserted in the question statement---"...then it's immediate that any of the other described circles is compact, too."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, either because of [Heine-Borel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem): a closed and bounded (in absolute value ) subset of $\Bbb C$ is compact, or by showing that all maps $f(z)= \alpha z$ are continuous (and have a continuous inverse when $\alpha \neq 0$ in $f^{-1}(z)=\frac{1}{\alpha}z$) and so preserve compactness (the continuous image of a compact set is compact as well).

Comment: Thank you. I've encountered the Heine-Borel theorem in the past so that makes sense, but is there a name for the property that a continuous function on a compact set is also compact, at least in the space of $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @stackexchangequestions2 It holds for all spaces (not just $\Bbb C$) and is an elementary standard fact that has no name in particular.

Comment: Someone has to have proven it. You're saying for any conceivable space at all, that I can take any conceivable continuous function on a compact set in that space, and it will also map to a compact set in that space? That doesn't seem like a trivial thing to prove, even if you also include bijectivity. Is there maybe a book that has a proof of that if not a specific person?

Comment: @stackexchangequestions2 Any topology book that covers compactness will prove it. Munkres, Engelking, Kelly, etc etc. It's rather easy to prove (just two or three lines) from the definitions, at least if you use the general definition (compact = every open cover has a finite subcover, continuous= the inverse image of any open set is open).

Comment: Alright well, I'll take your word for it and try to find a book then.

Answer (score 3):

Sure. Any two circles in the complex plane are homeomorphic. So, if one of them is compact, then all of them are.

Comment: Can you cite anything that proves anything you're saying? By which theorem are any two circles in the complex plane homeomorphic? By which other theorem do homeomorphisms preserve compactness? Those are very specific group-theoretic and topological properties.

Comment: If $C_r(z)$ is the circle centered at $z$ with radius $r$, then$$\begin{array}{ccc}C_1(0)&\longrightarrow&C_r(z)\\x&\mapsto&z+rx\end{array}$$is a homeomorphism. There was nothing group-thoretical in my answer (and neither in your question). And finally, it is soooooo obvious that homeomorphisms preserve compactnes that I will not waste my time searching for a reference for that.

Comment: Again, if it was obvious then there wouldn't be a field of math called "topology" to begin with, you're being very rude.

Comment: It is obvious that **any topological property whatsoever** is preserved by homeomorphisms. No deep theorem is needed to understand that.

Comment: Yes, nothing deep, just a branch of mathematics that was invented to address the fact that math wasn't deep enough to formalize proofs and explain contradictory results. This depends very much on what you mean by "any topological property" because there are a lot of things that could be considered topological properties. If you are referring to open sets mapping to open sets and closed sets mapping to closed sets, I could see that, but more general than that...